# android progressbar does not update when tasks are executed via threadpool

Tags: java, android, multithreading, user-interface, progress-bar

I read many **jpeg** files around 50 from SDCARD and store them on `Bitmap[]` 
for that I used thread pool as I wanted to read images as Quickly as Possible code does its task well but I want to Update Progressbar along with processing of Images as wanted to give feedback to user how much task is completed by thread pool.

problem is progressbar is Updated after thread pool finishes its tasks but I do send event updates in between of process.Here is how I execute thread pool and send update to progressbar via Handler but progressbar does not update thread pool takes all the CPU and hangs UI for Processing time and at last Progressbar gets updates.

```
    ExecutorService threadPool;
    CompletionService<ProcessedBitmap> pool;
    threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8);
    pool = new ExecutorCompletionService<ProcessedBitmap>(threadPool);
    for(int taskIndex = 0; taskIndex < preprocessingTasks.size(); taskIndex++)
    {
         try 
         {
             if(isCancelled)
             {
                 futureObjectList.get(taskIndex).cancel(true);
                 Utility.trace("Task Cancelled");
             }
             else
             {
                 Thread.sleep(10);
                 ProcessedBitmap result = pool.take().get();
                 images[result.getFrameIndex()] = result.getBitmap();
                 Message message = new Message();
                 message.what = PROGRESS_UPDATE;
                 message.arg1 = taskIndex;
                 handler.sendMessage(message);
             }
         }
         catch(Exception exception)
         {
             Utility.trace("Thread pool Exception :"+exception.getMessage());
         }
    }
    threadPool.shutdown();
    Message message = new Message();
    message.what = PRE_PROCESS_COMPLETE;
    message.obj =  images;
    handler.sendMessage(message);
```

Comment: Progress bar updates must be delivered on the main thread. What thread is this code running on, and what is `handler`?